# Dummy Variable Coefficients Excluded from Regression Output in R (no errors) (Time series plot unchanged)

Tags: r, regression, modeling, dummy-variable, coefficients

New to posting here, but not to the invaluable resources. Looked around and did not see anything that helped in my situation.
Running a fitted LogLinear regression model (successful) and when I attempted to adjust using "dummy" variables, I received no error. I also did not receive outputs for the dummyvars coefficients in my trend adjusted regression model.

Thank you for your time.

Data = souvenirs of `library(fpp3)`
code looks like :

```
library(fpp3)
# Data
tsdat <- souvenirs

# Model
fit_tsdat_dummy <- tsdat %>%
  mutate(DummyDec = month(Month) == 12) %>%
  model(TSLM(log(Sales) ~ trend() + season()))

report(fit_tsdat_dummy) # Coefficients expected here

# Produces the same plot as non-adjusted time-series plot 
# Validates no coefficients above, but why?)
augment(fit_tsdat_dummy) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Sales, colour = "Data")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = .fitted, colour = "Fitted")) +
  labs(x = "Month", 
       y = "Sales",
       title = "Monthly Sales")
```

[image]

Comment: Where is `s` defined?

Comment: Apologies - missed a replacement that should be tsdat (corrected, TY).

Comment: You don't seem to have included DummyDec in your model.

Comment: @AllanCameron, go to # Model, I should have defined it in the mutate(). Something off there?

Comment: @AAJ the mutate call creates the data, but you have to specifically include it in the model formula - maybe `TSLM(log(Sales) ~ trend() + season() + DummyDec)`

Comment: OMGoodness! That is my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

TWO ISSUES:

**1.** Did not call the Dummy variable in the model formula.

**2.** Collinearity was present, therefore NaN for the respective "duplicate" dummy.

Thank you.

NTS: Additional columns - flag check attribute.